# Variable call in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is extremely easy but I really can't solve it by myself. 
So, I have Jquery code:

```
$( ".ms-listviewtable th:nth-child(1)" ).css("background-color", "#97002e");
```

It works perfect, but, instead of 1 I'd like to use variable, e.g. `var abc=2` and I want `ab`c instead of 1 in my code. How can I call it?

Comment: Google for 'JavaScript string concatenation'. This really is the kind of simple thing you should be capable of researching yourself.

Comment: $( ".ms-listviewtable th:nth-child("+abc+")" ).css("background-color", "#97002e");

Comment: $( ".ms-listviewtable th:nth-child("+abc+")" ).css("background-color", "#97002e");

Comment: I got many answers in comments,

Comment: Thanks all - it was extremly easy, but I forgot about +.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a variable to your string.

```
var yourVariable = 1;
$( ".ms-listviewtable th:nth-child("+yourVariable+")" ).css("background-color", "#97002e");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc=2;
$(".ms-listviewtable th:nth-child("+abc+")").css("background-color","#97002e");
```